# Python- Selenium Webdriver opens firefox window but not the url

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am behind a proxy network. I have this a part of my python script:

```
PROXY_HOST = "10.3.100.212"

PROXY_PORT = 8080

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", PROXY_PORT)

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp", PROXY_HOST)

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp_port", PROXY_PORT)

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", PROXY_HOST)

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", PROXY_PORT)

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "localhost,127.0.0.1") 

br = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

br.get("http://google.com")
```

After the script is run, the Firefox window is opened but url is not loaded. I have checked the settings, it is correct and when I manual type google.com in that window, it opens up. Please tell me how to directly open any url.

Comment: your code works for me, testing with some random open proxy server. Not only it loads the page but also redirects to Google France as the proxy is there (and I am not). Python 2.7.2+ and Firefox 15.0 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: This problem is often seen if the browser version is not supported by selenium version one is using. Please provide the selenium and FF version you are using.

Comment: I have the similar issue , I have version 17.0.1 .. please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu.
I solved it by removing this line with proxy settings

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)